# 401 unauthorized connection using python-bitcoinrpc

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc

I'm running a Bitcoin testnet node on a Ubuntu 22.04 VM using UTM for Macbooks M1.

I'm trying to connect via json-rpc using https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc.

1 - I installed the package etc..

2 - I edited my .conf file in `/home/kk/snap/bitcoin-core/common/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf`:

```
server=1
testnet=1
daemon=1
prune=1000
fallbackfee=0.00001
rpcuser=kk
rpcpassword=testpass
rpcallowip=127.0.0.1
[test]
rpcbind=127.0.0.1
rpcport=18332
```

3 - I created a file called "btcrpc.py":

```python
from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy, JSONRPCException
from print import pprint

# rpc_user and rpc_password are set in the bitcoin. conf file
rpc_user = "kk"
rpc_pass = "testpass"
rpc_host = "127.0.0.1"
rpc_client = AuthServiceProxy(f'http://frpc_user}:{rpc_pass}@{rpc_host}:18332", timeout=120)

block_count = rpc_client.getblockcount()
print (block_count)
```

When I run btcrpc.py that's the error:

[image: Why is it unauthorized?]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```python
from bitcoinrpc.authproxy import AuthServiceProxy

rpc_user ="kk"
rpc_password="testpass"
rpc_port = "18332"

rpc_client = AuthServiceProxy("http://%s:%s@127.0.0.1:%s"%(rpc_user, rpc_password, rpc_port))

block_count = rpc_client.getblockcount()
print(block_count)
```

This code works and result was `2377824` for testnet. Although I would suggest not using [`python-bitcoinrpc`](https://github.com/jgarzik/python-bitcoinrpc) for anything on mainnet. Instead you can use [`python requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) and Bitcoin Core JSON-RPC.

Comment: Not working for me, maybe there is something wrong with my .config file or with its location. Any idea?

Comment: I managed to solve it by using your code and changing the .conf file: ``` testnet=1 daemon=1 prune=1000 fallbackfee=0.00001 server=1 [test] rpcport=18332 rpcallowip=127.0.0.1 rpcbind=127.0.0.1:18332 rpcuser=kk rpcpassword=testpass ```